# I need the graph to be ramp up,hold for sometime,rampdown (not all the way down)then rampup,hold for sometime,rampdown for a total of 4hrs test

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am using ultimate thread group in jmeter.I need the cycle should be a 5 minute ramp up, followed by by a 10 minute peak usage,followed by a 5 minute ramp down for a total of 4 hrs run time.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I gave first start thread count 25,intial delay 0, startup time 10sec, hold for 60 sec, and shout down time 10 sec. I don't want 25 users to ramp down, I want some user to rampdown and again rampup for the next thread. How can I control the user to rampdown and rampup again.